# sqlite3 timestamp column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I feel stupid, but I can't get a TIMESTAMP column to be shown in human understandable way in a SELECT.

I could do that in MySQL, not in sqlite3.

Could someone show me an example please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', datetime(birthday_field, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
AS birthday_year 
FROM birthdays;
```

The following is a complete list of valid [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) substitutions:

```
%d      day of month: 00
%f      fractional seconds: SS.SSS
%H      hour: 00-24
%j      day of year: 001-366
%J      Julian day number
%m      month: 01-12
%M      minute: 00-59
%s      seconds since 1970-01-01
%S      seconds: 00-59
%w      day of week 0-6 with sunday==0
%W      week of year: 00-53
%Y      year: 0000-9999
%%      %
```

Comment: accepted, for putting the effort into the answer, although you got inspired by munissor. He got only upvoted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SELECT datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');

Comment: **(,'** <-- where should it get the column from ??